# Pylint false positive for Flask's "app.logger": E1101: Method 'logger' has no 'debug' member (no-member)

Tags: python, logging, flask, pylint

Using flask's `app.logger` member functions (such as `app.logger.error`) causes `pylint` to report `E1101` (`no-member`) errors, even though these members of `app.logger` are defined at runtime.

This can be reproduced by using the following files:

**app.py**

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def say_hello():
    app.logger.debug('A debug message')
    app.logger.error('An error message')
    return 'hello'
```

**requirements.txt**

```
pylint==2.1.0
Flask==1.0.2
```

**Sample commands for reproducing the issue, using `virtualenv`:**

(Python 3.5 is used here, but the issue is not specific to that version)

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install pip==18.0
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And finally, running `pylint`:

```
pylint -E app
```

Returns these errors:

```
************* Module app
app.py:9:4: E1101: Method 'logger' has no 'debug' member (no-member)
app.py:10:4: E1101: Method 'logger' has no 'error' member (no-member)
```

Is there a good way to avoid these false positives?

Comment: pylint bug report: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2586

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to prevent these false positives, via pylint plugins:

**pylintplugins.py**

```
import sys

from astroid import MANAGER, scoped_nodes, extract_node
from astroid.builder import AstroidBuilder


def register(_linter):
    pass


def transform(f):
    if f.name == 'logger':
        for prop in ['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'addHandler']:
            f.instance_attrs[prop] = extract_node('def {name}(arg): return'.format(name=prop))


MANAGER.register_transform(scoped_nodes.FunctionDef, transform)
```

This workaround prevents linting errors on `app.logger.debug`, `app.logger.info`, `app.logger.warning`, `app.logger.error` and `app.logger.addHandler`.

In order to be used, the **pylintplugins.py** file needs to be loaded using the `--load-plugins` command line option:

```
PYTHONPATH="." pylint -E app --load-plugins pylintplugins
```

or by including the following line in the `pylintrc` configuration file:

```
load-plugins=pylintplugins
```

Answer (score 21):

Use `create_logger` instead.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.logging import create_logger

APP = Flask(__name__)
LOG = create_logger(APP)


@APP.route('/')
def say_hello():
    LOG.debug('A debug message')
    LOG.error('An error message')
    return 'hello'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, that worked for me and does not include writing an extra plugin is to set `generated-members` in my `.pylintrc`:

```
...
[TYPECHECK]
generated-members=app.logger
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Also note that if you are importing `app` via another python file (such as a view file when using Blueprints):

1. If you import app like this, you will get lint errors on `app.logger.info`:

   `from myapp import app`
2. If you import app like this, you won't get lint errors on `app.logger.info`:

   `from flask import current_app as app`

From the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/):

> Flask solves this issue with the application context. Rather than referring to an app directly, you use the the current_app proxy, which points to the application handling the current activity.

I don't have a good answer as to why, but it works for me using `pylint==2.2.2` on `python3.6.6`. As always, your milage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer from Yan QiDong:

You can also create the logger yourself:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask.logging import create_logger

app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger = create_logger(app)
```

This way you can work as usual with `app.logger.warning("Starting the HTTP server...")` and `pylint` won't complain.

Otherwise you could invoke it like `pylint --disable=E1101 src/`, but this means you are happy to ignore **ALL** those `E1101` errors.

Comment: PLEASE nobody disable `E1101` (`no-member`) in your projects...