# Visual Studio Code pylint looking at plugins only in site-packages

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm using the pylint plugin described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51678586/11323942) in Visual Studio Code.

I have entered the following in the `settings.json`

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins","pylintplugins"],
}
```

My problem (found after a few hours of research, see also my second question below) is that I have to place `pylintplugins.py` under `venv\Lib\site-packages`: why is that happening and how can I instruct pylint from Visual Studio Code to look under my project root folder instead?

Notice that I have a `PYTHONPATH` pointing to my project root folder and that running from the terminal

```
pylint --load-plugins pylintplugins -E sample00.py
```

is OK.

A second question, if possible. When I move `pylintplugins.py` under my project root folder and pylint from Visual Studio Code can't find it, it **silently** fails: Studio Code simply stops showing the lint problems when I open a python file. It has been difficult for me to understand what was going wrong: where is a log of Visual Studio or something where one is supposed to find such a problem for `python.linting`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've found to make pylint read the path of the plugin from Visual Studio Code is

1. put the following .pylintrc under the **project root folder** opened from Visual Studio Code

   [MASTER]

   load-plugins=C:/my/project/root/pylintplugins
2. write the **absolute** path **(*)** of the project root folder as shown above

### Second Question

Look at the OUTPUT tab of Visual Studio code and select Python from the dropdown list.
You will find there how it is calling pylint.

**(*)** In my case, since I didn't like the idea of keeping an absolute path, I ended up leveraging the init-hook option to run the following python commands as initialization (the current path is the work-dir and it is added to the sys path where it was missing, there you will find the python plugins file)

```
[MASTER]
init-hook="import sys; import os; sys.path.append(os.getcwd());"
load-plugins=pylintplugins
```